# Where to find source code for java.lang native methods?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native

I'm vaguely familiar with the [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), and I'm curious to see my machine-specific implementation for some native methods in the java.lang package. `Thread#currentThread()`, for example.

I've found a bunch of DLLs in [JDK_HOME]/jre/bin, but like I said I'm trying to find the source code.

Does anyone know where the native source code can be found? Is it even available, or is it classified by Sun (oops I mean "We're In It To Win It" Oracle)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For JDK6 you can download the source from [java.net](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/). For `java.lang` the story begins at `j2se/src/share/native/java/lang/`, and then search... JDK7 rearranges the directory structure a little.

Some methods, such as `Object.hashCode`, may be implemented by hotspot instead or in addition to through JNI/Java.

JDK6 is freely licensed through the Java Research License (JRL) and Java Internal Use License (JIUL). JDK7 and OpenJDK6 is licensed under GPL 2 with CLASSPATH exception (roughly speaking you can link to it without catching the GNU virus). I am not a lawyer.

(<strike>BTW: The real lawyers would like to point out that I am still an employee of Sun Microsystems.</strike> Sun UK is no more. It is *now* Oracle.)

Update (Adding location for Thread.c):
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/native/java/lang/Thread.c

Comment: Sort-of through HotSpot, though mostly through the `JVM_*` interface (what _is_ that interface called?), which provides a fairly nice abstraction layer for the VM itself.

Comment: I especially enjoy the fact that the bytecode verifier is implemented using _only_ JNI and the `JVM_*` interface, without touching any HotSpot internals. :-)

Answer (score 12):

You can look at the source code for [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) (licensed under [GPLv2 with Classpath Exception](http://openjdk.java.net/legal/gplv2+ce.html)). Probably the best way to study the JDK implementation internals, unless you want to be bound by the [Java Research Licence](http://www.java.net/jrl.csp), in which case you can access the actual [JDK 6 source](https://jdk6.dev.java.net/).