# Where can I find the Java native method implementations?

Tags: java, java-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to find source code for java.lang native methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292629/where-to-find-source-code-for-java-lang-native-methods)

Where can I find Java’s native method implementations of JDK 1.6 Windows platform?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292629/where-to-find-source-code-for-java-lang-native-methods

Answer (score 0):

Here is how Googles Dalvik VM implements it, I can't imagine the windows  or any other version to be much different.

```
 241 /*
 242  * static long currentTimeMillis()
 243  *
 244  * Current time, in miliseconds.  This doesn't need to be internal to the
 245  * VM, but we're already handling java.lang.System here.
 246  */
 247 static void Dalvik_java_lang_System_currentTimeMillis(const u4* args,
 248     JValue* pResult)
 249 {
 250     struct timeval tv;
 251 
 252     UNUSED_PARAMETER(args);
 253 
 254     gettimeofday(&tv, (struct timezone *) NULL);
 255     long long when = tv.tv_sec * 1000LL + tv.tv_usec / 1000;
 256 
 257     RETURN_LONG(when);
 258 }
```

[Source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=blob;f=vm/native/java_lang_System.c;h=4af0dfa425974b46c791e675264ec7aa9fafb2d6;hb=HEAD)

Comment: Right but where did you find that code?

Comment: @maerics Source is linked at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on which VM you are using. The sources of the Sun / Oracle JDKs can be found here:

> http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/