# Native Methods - java

Tags: java

where to find the source code of the machine specific native methods declared in java...

For example **private static native Class forName0(String name, boolean initialize,
                        ClassLoader loader)**

Comment: Possible duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292629/where-to-find-source-code-for-java-lang-native-methods

Answer (score 2):

Use [Google code search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) (see [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch#search&q=Class+forName0) for the search results).

You'll be looking for C code from the JDK implementation.