# Why we call Thread.start() method which in turns calls run method?

Tags: java, multithreading

Why do we call the thread object's `start()` method which in turns calls `run()` method, why not we directly call `run()` method?

Answer (score 72):

> ***[...] why not we directly call run() method?***

The `run()` method is just an ordinary method (overridden by *you*). As with any other ordinary method and calling it directly will cause the *current thread* to execute `run()`.

All magic happens inside `start()`. The `start()` method will cause the JVM to spawn a new thread and make the newly spawned thread execute `run()`.

Comment: but the start is eventually calling start0() in the same class, what does start0() do.?

Comment: The contract of the class (described in the javadoc) says that you get the forking behavior by calling the public `start` method. What's basically all that matters. Whether or not the magic happens directly in `start` or if it delegates to another method depends on the API implementation. If you're referring to `Thread.java` in OpenJDK, it does indeed look like it delegates to a `start0`. I bet this method doesn't contain the "magic" either. I bet it delegates to some `fork()` system call. In the end this depends on the operating system. Again, it's an JDK/OS implementation detail.

Comment: @aioobe I believe the threads are created more with the help of some sort of OS thread manager and not fork system call. Fork system call is used to clone the current process and create a new process out of it and not a new thread

Comment: Right. I'm no system level programmer so I was basically guessing  Some Googling tells me `clone()` is probably what's used on Linux systems (which incidentally calls `do_fork()`).

Answer (score 25):

If you directly call run() method its body is executed in context of current thread. When you invoke `start()` method a new thread is created and `run()` method is executed in this new thread.

Answer (score 17):

Even if programmatically we are not creating any thread, For every application, O.S will create a default thread to execute its code with CPU.

Calling run method directly will make that run method execute in that main thread given by O.S.

But the intention of creating a thread class is to make sure that run method executes in a different thread. Unless thread manager of O.S creates a thread, your run method will not get executed in a separate thread. To request O.S to create the separate thread you have to call start() method which will send a request to O.S to create a thread. Once O.S creates a thread, then O.S will automatically call run method of your thread class in that newly created thread context. And hence your purpose of creating a separate thread and executing your run method in a separate thread will be served.

If you call run method directly, then it is like O.S is not creating any thread for you, and default main thread will execute your run method. 
No point of creating a separate thread class for that!

Hope I am clear. Let me know if you need more explanation to answer your question.

Note: Though books say JVM creates threads, internally JVM will have to send a request to thread manager driver of O.S layer to create a new thread in its thread pool. That's why I use O.S term more here than JVM.

Comment: This is the bset answer so far!

Answer (score 10):

> Why do we call the thread object's start() method which in turns calls
>   run() method

No it doesn't. `start()` calls the operating system, which starts a new thread, which (to simplify greatly) calls the `run()` method. Meanwhile the `start()` method has already returned to its caller. They are not equivalent.

Comment: This's best answer. :)

Answer (score 9):

`Runnable` is just an interface.  A class implementing `Runnable` is nothing special, it just has a `run` method.

`Thread#start` is a natively implemented method that creates a separate thread and calls `Thread`'s `run` method, executing the code in the new thread.

`Thread` implements `Runnable`.  The code for `run` looks like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

If the `Thread` instance was created by passing a `Runnable` to the `Thread`'s constructor, the `Runnable`'s `run` method is called.

Otherwise, classes extending `Thread` have to override the `run` method in order for `start` to work.

Calling `run` on `Thread` does NOT create a new thread.

Answer (score 4):

If a thread has been instantiated but not started its is said to be in **new state**. 
Unless until a start() method is invoked on the instance of the thread, it will not said to be alive.
 If you do not call a start() method on the newly created thread instance thread is not considered to be alive.
 If the start() method is not invoked and the run() method is directly called on the Thread instance, the code inside the **run() method will not run in a separate new thread but it will start running in the existing thread**.

**SEE THE PROBLEM IN EXAMPLE**

```
class Multi extends Thread{  
 public void run(){  
  for(int i=1;i<5;i++){  
    try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println(e);}  
    System.out.println(i);  
  }  
 }  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
  Multi t1=new Multi();  
  Multi t2=new Multi();  

  t1.run();  
  t2.run();  
 }  
}  

Output:1
       2
       3
       4
       5
       1
       2
       3
       4
       5
```

As you can see in the above program that there is no context-switching because here t1 and t2 will be treated as normal object not thread object.

Answer (score 4):

It's due to the design of multithreading in Java.

Calling `start ()` will start a new Thread and calling `run()` method does not start a new Thread.

If you call `start()` method on Thread, Java Virtual Machine will call run() method and two threads will run concurrently now - Current Thread  and Other Thread  or Runnable implementation.

Have a look at source code of `start()` method in [Thread class](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java/?v=source)

```
 /**
     * Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine
     * calls the <code>run</code> method of this thread.
     * <p>
     * The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the
     * current thread (which returns from the call to the
     * <code>start</code> method) and the other thread (which executes its
     * <code>run</code> method).
     * <p>
     * It is never legal to start a thread more than once.
     * In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed
     * execution.
     *
     * @exception  IllegalThreadStateException  if the thread was already
     *               started.
     * @see        #run()
     * @see        #stop()
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        /**
         * This method is not invoked for the main method thread or "system"
         * group threads created/set up by the VM. Any new functionality added
         * to this method in the future may have to also be added to the VM.
         *
         * A zero status value corresponds to state "NEW".
         */
        if (threadStatus != 0)
            throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
        group.add(this);
        start0();
        if (stopBeforeStart) {
            stop0(throwableFromStop);
        }
    }

    private native void start0();
```

In above code, you can't see invocation to `run()` method.

`private native void start0()` is responsible for calling `run()` method. JVM creates native thread corresponding to java thread and call `run()` method.

Refer to this question for source code of native methods:

[Where to find source code for java.lang native methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292629/where-to-find-source-code-for-java-lang-native-methods)

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 1):

When we use start method then a new thread is created and then code inside the run method will be executed for each new Thread.

Use of start method creates two stack for each thread ,Stack and native stack.

But `Run` method call just `execute` the code inside the `run` method sequentially as run method call does not create different stacks.

Example

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class thread implements Runnable{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread gg=new Thread(new thread());
        Thread gg1=new Thread(new thread());
        gg.run();
        gg1.start();
        /*gg.start();
        gg1.start();*/

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println("Hello..." + i);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are talking about starting a thread. If that's the case the reason you don't invoke the run method directly is that you then would be calling the method, and not starting the thread.

Answer (score 0):

If we want, we can call `run()` method, but if we call run method it will run as just a normal Java method. Whereas it we call `start(`) it, `JVM` creates a new thread and run method will be executed on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

`start()` and `run()` methods are used for running a thread.The `run()` method is just an ordinary method, it is overridden by the user and it will be called on the current thread.
The `start()` method runs the `run()` method indirectly and creates a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that if we execute the run method by `start()` method, it creates a new thread where we can execute run method otherwise the `run()` method will be executed in the thread created by JVM in the `public static void main()` method. This is exactly the whole point of multithreading, to run a different action on new threads.