# Why does my Thread freeze the UI-Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, networking, freeze, ui-thread

I cant figure it out.

For what ever reason, this thread's code is actually running on the UI thread.
If i break point it the UI stops. or Sleep it, UI stopped. and hence network activity is unallowed as its on the "ui" thread.

Ive not used Async task, because I am unaware of the proper way of looping it. (calling a new instance of it in `onPostExecute` seems like bad practice, and as if async is for one off tasks.

I extend Thread.

```
public class SyncManager  extends Thread {

public SyncManager(Context context){
    sdb = new SyncManagerDBHelper(context);
    mContext = context;     
}

@Override
public void run() {     

    while(State == RUNNING) {
        try{
            SyncRecords();   // Break point here = UI freeze.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000); // So also causes UI freeze.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

 public void startThread() {
    Log.i("SyncManager", "start called");

    if((State == PAUSED || State == STOPPED) && !this.isAlive() )
    {
        State = RUNNING;
        run();      
    }   
}
```

ANd from my Activity I call

```
  sm = new SyncManager(this);
  sm.startThread();
```

Comment: Look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052522/why-we-call-thread-start-method-which-in-turns-calls-run-method/36812010#36812010

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use `Thread.start()` to start any new thread. 
As far as I know calling `run()` directly **will not cause the system to actually launch a new thread**, hence your blocking UI.

Change your `startThread()` method to the following and it should then work:

```
public class SyncManager extends Thread {

    public void startThread() {

        if((State == PAUSED || State == STOPPED) && !this.isAlive()) {
            State = RUNNING;
            start();  // use start() instead of run()
        }   
    }
}
```

[**Read here**](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/difference-between-start-and-run-method.html) for more specific information from the Java revisited blog.

Comment: Sigh, I knew it was a silly question. Ironically I wrote a test Thread, and put `start();` That being said, if I hadnt asked, i'd have wasted more hours figuring it out. It does make sense now. Calling `run()` just calling the method on the UI thread, as would calling any method directly. Thanks!

Comment: 2 year latter and yes, it helped me =D