# Both call execute thread then why first one is called valid

Tags: java

I have created one demo class to test how to create thread by extending thread class. As we need to invoke `start()` on class object to call `run()` , but if I invoke `run()` directly by invoking it on class object it also get run. As it gets run then why should we call `start()` on class object to invoke `run()`

```
public class Derived extends Thread{

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Run.....");
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]){
        Derived derivedThread = new Derived();   
        derivedThread.start();

    }

}
```

Above is the valid way, but when I call run() directly like,

```
public class Derived extends Thread{

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Run.....");
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]){
        Derived derivedThread = new Derived();

        //derivedThread.start();
        derivedThread.run();
    }

}
```

Above code also run successfully.

Then why we call thread by first way. Can somebody clear it? Will appreciate your help.

Comment: Nothing surprising, since [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) implements `Runnable`.

Comment: To see the difference put a Thread.sleep(1000) in your run() method and a println(....) just after you start or run your object. Run should be running synchronously when you call run but asynchronously when you call start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why we call Thread.start() method which in turns calls run method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052522/why-we-call-thread-start-method-which-in-turns-calls-run-method)

Answer (score 0):

There will be no thread created when you call the `run()`. It will act as an method call and do what is in the `run()` method.

But in the other hand. the `start()` will create a thread. and what the thread do is in the `run()` method