# Recursive calling of run method due to Thread.currentThread().run()

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

i am new to multithreading and trying to clear my basics.

```
public class SleepExample extends Thread {

private int counter = 0;

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        counter++;
        System.out.println("Value of counter "+counter);
        System.out.println("Thread going in sleep "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.currentThread().run();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Thread out of sleep "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SleepExample().start();
    new SleepExample().start();
    Test test = new  Test();
    Thread t = new Thread(test);
    t.start();
}
}

//another class implementing runnable

public class Test implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("In Test runnable method");

}
```

}

When i run this code, my run method of SleepExample recursively call itself after below line

```
Thread.currentThread().run();
```

for thread belonging to SleepExample (Thread -0, Thread -1) and
 it goes to run method of Test class for thread t.

I am unable to understand the usage of  Thread.currentThread().run();

P.S. - I read its java doc and so i have implemented a runnable

Comment: Calling `Thread.currentThread().run();` unconditionally seems like a very bad idea. `Thread.run()` is just a regular method, so this will result in a `StackOverflowError`. Even calling it conditionally seems highly questionable - I can't see why you'd want to do this. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for reply.I was just trying to implement and learn.Yes it did cause exception due to recursive call to run method.

Comment: @Narendra Pandey : Refer to this question for more details on start() and run() methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052522/why-we-call-thread-start-method-which-in-turns-calls-run-method/36812010#36812010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unable to understand the usage of Thread.currentThread().run();

You are not supposed to call it directly. From [Thread.start()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--) You are supposed to use `start()` to call `run()` and that is it.

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the **run** method of this thread.
>
> The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run method).
>
> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

You are already running in the `run()` so you should only call this if you can say why you are doing it, even then it will look like a bug or be plain confusing and I would suggest you use a loop instead.

> When i run this code, my run method of SleepExample recursively call itself after below line

You have a method calling itself, so you should expect that to happen. There is nothing special to `Thread` in this regard. It is like any other recursive call in a method.

Comment: Thanks, got it. **Thread.currentThread().run()** need to be called from main method after t.start()

Comment: @NarendraPandey This method never needs to be called explicitly.