# Can there be zombie threads in a java program?

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

Consider the folowing code:

```java
public... main( String[] args ) // yeah yeah, I'm too lazy to type it out
    new ThreadExample().start(); // the run function just prints out "this is run"
}
```

Now, it may so happen that the moment the call to start is made, the scheduler switches back to the main and the main block ends. What will happen to the thread that the start method created? There's still a non-daemon thread running (the one we created) meaning the program should continue execution or it can become a zombie thread (I still don't fully understand what that entails...).
What might (or what passes for "might" in the absence of synchronization) happen?

---

Edit:

This question is better rephrased as: "What exactly does the start() method call do?"
More may be found at: [Why do we call Thread.start() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052522/why-we-call-thread-start-method-which-in-turns-calls-run-method)

Comment: From the [documentation of `Thread` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html): "*Platform threads are designated daemon or non-daemon threads. When the Java virtual machine starts up, there is usually one non-daemon thread (the thread that typically calls the application's main method). The shutdown sequence begins when all started non-daemon threads have terminated. Unstarted non-daemon threads do not prevent the shutdown sequence from beginning.*"

Comment: And for completeness: [Shutdown Sequence (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#shutdown)

Comment: I'm still new to the multi-threading in Java world... I don't understand a word written there :( All I have gathered till now is that the jvm exits whenever one of the three conditions are met.

Comment: In short: the JVM waits until all running non-daemon threads are terminated and starts the shutdown sequence. If, for any reason, there should still be a thread runing during the shutdown sequence, the thread gets terminated.

Comment: So will the non-main thread run or...?

Comment: Maybe. It depends whether it is started before the `main`-method terminates. If it started before the `main`-method terminates, it will prevent the JVM form terminating. See [this `ideone.com` demo](https://ideone.com/Ilw9zX).

Comment: @Turing85 will that depend on the fact that the main method does not end after the call to start in the example?

Comment: Again: It depends whether the new `Thread` is started before the `main`-method terminates.

Comment: Ok, I'm lost :( How will it ever not start before the main method terminates?

Comment: @queeg, see the discussion about what `start()` means in comments on dan1st's answer, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

In your example, the thread will be started and the JVM won't shutdown until that thread also terminates (unless a different shutdown event is triggered). You don't need extra synchronization for that.

### longer description

You are starting the thread in your main method.
Because the `start()` method finishes before the `main` method stops, the application will *not* shut down. As mentioned in the comments of your question (and also directly in your question), the JVM doesn't attempt to shut down before all non-daemon threads are stopped.

When you create a thread, it will be in [`ThreadState.NEW`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.State.html) but as soon as you have called `start()`, it [will be in `ThreadState.RUNNABLE`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/runtime/thread.cpp#L382) (or similar if it had already performed some work) and will stop the application from shutting down.

```java
Thread t = new Thread(()->{
    //you can do something here if you want to
});
t.start();
System.out.println(t.getState());//this will never be NEW
```

If a thread is neither `NEW` nor `TERMINATED`, it [is alive](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive()) hence it it will prevent the JVM from shutting down.

So, your second thread would continue running until it finishes or something else stops the JVM.

As soon as you call `Thread#start`, you have a thread preventing the JVM from shutting down, no matter whether the thread actually started working.

However, as [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77423883/can-there-be-zombie-threads-in-a-java-program#comment136493899_77423883), this can be different if `Thread#start` is invoked after the last non-daemon thread has stopped. If the JVM is already shutting down, calling `Thread#start` on another thread won't cancel shutdown.

If the last non-daemon thread stops and a daemon thread attempts to start a non-daemon thread "at the same time", you will have a race condition and the thread might win or be stopped.
If the thread is actually marked as started before the last (non-daemon thread) thread stops, it will run normally and the JVM won't shutdown.
However, if the JVM detects all threads are stopped before the new thread is marked as started/`RUNNABLE`, the JVM would initiate the shutdown sequence and kill the newly started thread after all shutdown hooks finish.

If you are using virtual threads, it should be noted that these always are daemon threads.

Comment: The `start()` method finishing does not imply that the thread has actually started. So there is a race condition. The JVM may well exit.

Comment: Could this be verified by calling `start()` twice? The second one should fail as the thread is no longer in NEW state...

Comment: *"Could this be verified by calling start() twice?"*  No.  Well yea it will fail.  But that doesn't actually prove anything.  You would also need to prove that the test `threadstatus != 0` in `Thread.start` is the only thing that can cause `IllegalThreadStateException` to be thrown in this case (Hint: look at the native code!).

Comment: But I *suspect* (but can't prove) that the `Thread` will be in practice be "alive" for the purposes of process exit determination before `start()` returns ... irrespective of whether the (OS) thread scheduler has actually started the new native thread.  (If there was a race condition for this, I would have expected it to be documented.  But I'm going to do some Googling ...)

Comment: Best evidence I can find so far (not proof!) is that the Java 21 javadoc for Thread.setDaemon says: *"Marks this thread as either a daemon or non-daemon thread. The shutdown sequence begins when all started non-daemon threads have terminated."*.   There is no precise specification of what "started" means,  but the intuitive meaning would be that `start()` has been called.  There is no mention I can see of a race condition in this respect.  (And nobody appears to have raised an OpenJDK bug about this hypothetical race condition.)

Comment: @user207421, Can you cite documentation that says or implies that there is a race between the return from the `start()` call and the moment when the `Thread` instance is put into a state that prevents the JVM from shutting down? Is there OpenJDK code that proves it? It would be much more friendly of the library architects to declare that the `Thread` is _officially_ "started" as soon as `start()` returns, and never mind what state the OS thinks it's in.

Comment: The [Shutdown Sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#class-description) mentions: "when the number of live non-daemon threads drops to zero for the first time (see note below on the JNI Invocation API);" which links to [Thread#isAlive](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#) which states that it's "not yet staarted" and `start()` immediately marks it as started (i.e. the thread isn't `NEW` any more but `RUNNABLE` as I mentioned in my answer including a link to the native Hotspot source).

Comment: Java doesn't have an in-between state of `start()` called but not yet started. Either the thread is started (as soon as `start()` has been called) or it is `NEW`.

Comment: @user85421 yes, this is what I linked in my answer (the "will be in `ThreadState.RUNNABLE`" part).

Comment: The javadoc for [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) states that this method "Schedules this thread to begin execution." and does not guarantee that the thread is started soon as this method is called. I feel that @user207421 is right and the program in question should lead to a race condition. However, this begs the logical question, why do we have an `unStarted()` function?

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him, Why would the library designers allow that race condition when they could just as easily prevent it?

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him [From the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html): "A thread will start when the `start()` method is invoked on the corresponding `Thread` object." [and](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4) "An action that starts a thread _synchronizes-with_ the first action in the thread it starts."

Answer (score 0):

FYI: You may have heard of "zombies" from Linux. Linux, processes refer to other processes by their system-wide *PIDs* (Process IDs). The OS re-uses PIDs, but it will never re-use PID C* until some live process P* has received notification that C has died and, that its PID no longer is valid. That happens when P calls [`wait()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) or one of several other, similar system calls.

A *zombie process* in Linux simply is the PID of some dead process for which no other living process has yet received the death notice. If process P itself dies without ever waiting for its zombie child C, then the `init` process will `wait` for both of them, and the zombie will be reaped.

The only way that zombies can be a problem is if process P runs for a long time and continually creates new children without ever `wait`ing for any of them. PIDs are a limited resource, and eventually, the process table could be so clogged with zombies that [`fork()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) calls start failing with `ENOMEM`.

---

I'm not aware of anything similar happening with Java threads. The Java `Thread` object representing a dead thread gets managed (garbage collected) just like any other Java object, and if the OS requires some kind of cleanup after the underlying *native* thread has ended, AFAIK, the JVM is supposed to  automatically take care of that for you.

---

* I'm using "P" for "parent" and "C" for "child" because that's the most common way for one process to know the PID of another.