# JDK Native Code Implementation

Tags: jvm, java-native-interface, native, java

I would like to know if it is possible to get the Native Code implementation of JDK methods, such as:

```
public final class System {

/* First thing---register the natives */
private static native void registerNatives();
...
....}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to find source code for java.lang native methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292629/where-to-find-source-code-for-java-lang-native-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for OpenJDK source code (it is open source), or any other open-source Java implementation and you can find the implementations.

The [System class source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/System.java?av=f) for example (grabbing the [complete OpenJDK source](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/) might be more convenient than this 'web view').

Note: `registerNatives()` is using native (C/C++ ?) code, so you'd need to track that down (from the complete source code for example). Or any other implementation you are interested in.

Comment: The question is **about** native code, so no wonder it seems to be using it :)

Comment: True :) But my answer is more in the line of 'choose your favorite open-source Java implementation and check out the code, with an OpenJDK example'. More like a pointer than the exact answer, so it is more generic applicable.

Comment: Except it misses the crucial link to the actual piece of code. Java source code is trivially easy to look up.

Answer (score 1):

Above part of code is not enough to implement native method, you can find detailed information  http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip23.html

Answer (score 1):

All this is available from the OpenJDK Mercurial repo web view, but it is far from trivial to track down.

[This here is a link to `java.lang.System`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/fdd0d43ba0f9/src/share/native/java/lang/System.c) native code in the newest development version of JDK 7 Update stream. Hopefully you'll find your way around from there.