# What is the default implementation of `hashCode`?

Tags: java, hashcode

If one does not override the `hashCode` method, what is the default implementation of `hashCode` ?

Comment: About default implementation you can read [this](http://blogs.tedneward.com/CommentView,guid,eca26c5e-307c-4b7c-931b-2eaf5b176e98.aspx)

Comment: default implementation is JVM specific, but in general it returns `return Objects.hash(this.field1, this.field2, this.field3, etc.);`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Then this class inherits `hashCode` from one of its ancestors. If non of them overrides it, then [Object.hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) is used.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)

So default implementation is JVM-specific

Comment: Thank you, yes. What does the implementation of `Object.hashCode() look` like?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood it's an implementation detail, you need to address your JVM docs for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32454673/6785908

Answer (score 17):

By default, methods that are not overriden are inherited from `Object`.

If you look at that method's documentation, the return values are "`[...] distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer [...])`". The method in `java.lang.Object` is declared as native, which means the implementation is provided by the JVM and may vary depending on your runtime environment.

A small example:

```
Object o1 = new Object();
Object o2 = new Object();
System.out.println(o1.hashCode());
System.out.println(o2.hashCode());
```

prints (using my jdk6):

```
1660187542
516992923
```

A Hex representation of the `hashCode()` value is used in the default implementation of `toString()` by the way: Running `System.out.println(o1)` prints something like

```
java.lang.Object@7a5e1077
```

Answer (score 7):

Object.hashcode() is a native method.

`public native int hashCode();`

That means it's implemented in platform specific code and is exposed as a native method.

code for the same will be a compiled code and not available withing JDK

this [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292629/where-to-find-source-code-for-java-lang-native-methods) might provide more info.