# Java clone() inquiry

Tags: java, clone

Having written the code below, I was wondering why clone() doesn't return the same hashcode for each additional instance. Am I doing something wrong?

```
public class Accessor implements Cloneable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Accessor one = new Accessor();
    Accessor two = one.clone();

    System.out.println("one hahcod  " + one.hashCode()
    +"\ntwo hashcode " + two.hashCode());    

    }

    public Accessor clone(){

        try{

            return (Accessor)super.clone();

        }
        catch (CloneNotSupportedException err){

            throw new Error("Error!!!");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Because it is a different object. You are invoking the cloning inherited from Object in this case. For each new object you will have a different dashcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Accessor` does not override `hashCode`, you will get the default implementation of `Object.hashCode`. This has implementation-defined semantics but will basically cast the address of the object to an integer, such that distinct object instances will have different `hashCode`s.

See [What is the default implementation of `hashCode`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130764/what-is-the-default-implementation-of-hashcode) for more information on the above.

Note that if you are going to implement `hashCode`, you should also implement `equals`. For a good reference on `equals` and `hashCode`, read Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java* (or see [Best implementation for hashCode method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/best-implementation-for-hashcode-method))

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a different object. You are invoking the cloning inherited from Object in this case. For each new object you will have a different dashcode. If you open the source code of Object in java what you will find there is the following:

```
 public native int hashCode();

public boolean More ...equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
```

The key point here is that once you clone an object A clone of B A==B will always return false.

Then if you read the hashcode documentation it states the following :

> If two
>   objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling
>   the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same
>   integer result. **It is not required that if two objects are unequal
>   according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the
>   hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct
>   integer results.** However, the programmer should be aware that
>   producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the
>   performance of hashtables.

Answer (score 1):

The clone method creates a shallow copy of your first object but your *Accessor* class has no instance field and does not override [hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) method, as a consequence the instances of this class get the default behaviour from Object class for *hashCode*. This behaviour is similar as calling [System#identityHashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-) with your object as parameter.