# Deserialization of JavaScript array to Java LinkedHashSet using Jackson and Spring doesn't remove duplicates

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

Let's say I have this client-side JSON input:

```
{
   id: "5",
   types: [
      {id: "1", types:[]},
      {id: "2", types:[]},
      {id: "1", types[]}
   ]
}
```

I have this class:

```
class Entity {
    private String id;
    private Set<Entity> types = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Entity> getTypes() {
        return types;
    }

    @JsonDeserialize(as=LinkedHashSet.class)
    public void setTypes(Set<Entity> types) {
        this.types = types;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if (o == null || !(o instanceof Entity)){
            return false;
        }
        return this.getId().equals(((Entity)o).getId());
    }
}
```

I have this Java Spring endpoint where I pass the input in the body of a [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/entity", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Entity createEntity(@RequestBody final Entity in) {
    Set<Entity> types = in.getTypes();
    [...]
}
```

I would like in:

`Set<Entity> types = in.getTypes();`

to have only two entries in the correct order... since one of them is a duplicate based on the id...
Instead I get duplicates in the LinkedHashSet (!)

I thought from the code I have that removing duplicates would work automatically, but apparently it is not.

This question has a broader context than *[Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)*
since it is using implicit Jackson serialization through Java Spring.

Comment: Where is your `hashCode()` function?

Comment: It's part of the contract same as `equals(Object)`.

Comment: Thanks! it seems I am missing that - let me add it and see if it works

Comment: @GurwinderSingh It worked!! You can add that as an answer and I will accept it if you want :)

Comment: for this simple scenario and since I might have different classes with the same id I used:
      ```@Override
 public int hashCode() {
  return ("entity-"+this.getId()).hashCode();
 }```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only overriding `equals` method will not work because hash-based collections use both the `equals` and `hashCode` method to see if two objects are the same. You'll need to override `hashCode()` method in `Entity` class as both `hashCode()` and `equals()` method are required to be properly implemented to work with Hash based collections.

If your requirement is that if the some or all of the fields of two objects of the `Entity` class are same, then the two objects are to be considered equivalent, in that case, you'll have to override both `equals()` and `hashCode()` method.

For e.g. - if only `id` field in the Entity class is required to determine if the two objects are equal, then you'll override `equals()`, something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (o instanceof Entity){
        Entity that = (Entity) o;
        return this.id == null ? that.id == null : this.id.equals(that.id);
    }
    return false;

}
```

but along with it, the `hashCode()` method need to be overridden in a way to produce same hashcode if id has the same value, maybe something like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int h = 17;
    h = h * 31 + id == null ? 0 : id.hashCode();
    return h;
}
```

Only now it'll work properly with Hash based collections, as both these methods are used to identify an object uniquely.

---

More on this:

- [Relationship between hashCode and equals method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027777/relationship-between-hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java)
- [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that if the members of `Entity` class i.e. the `id` and `type` are same then the object of class `Entity` is same is completely wrong unless and until you override the `hashcode()` and `equals()` function explicitly.

If you do not override the `hashCode()` and `equals()` function in your `Entity` class then the two objects will be different even though they have same data within their members.

Comment: well I forgot ```hashCode()``` - I thought that hash based collections were using ```equals()``` to determine if it is the same object..

Comment: @MichailMichailidis You should always consider overriding both `hashCode()` as well as `equals()` and not just one. I hope this resolves your problem :)

Comment: yeap I figured it out based on Gurwinder's answer that came a bit earlier :) Thanks

Comment: @MichailMichailidis Cheers! :)

Answer (score 3):

In Java, objects equality is determined by overriding the `equals()` and `hashcode()` [contract](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074996/hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java-object---a-pragmatic-concept.html).

There are default implementations of `equals()` and `hashCode()` in Object. If you don't provide your own implementation, those will be used. For `equals()`, this means an `==` comparison: the objects will only be equal if they are exactly the same object.

**Answer to your question** : Objects  in `LinkedHashSet` are inheriting default behaviour of `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods from `Object` class. Override `equals()` and `hashcode()` of `Entity` class of `LinkedHashSet`

See below [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130764/what-is-the-default-implementation-of-hashcode) for default behaviour of `hashcode()` and `equals()`.