# Where can i find the code for native method implementation?

Tags: java

I was going through the thread class in java and found that most of its methods like sleep(), yield(), currentThread() are native. I know the meaning of native keyword but how can i check the JNI implementation for these methods?

Comment: From the OpenJDK repo, here's where Thread's methods are registered: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/3ad03712ea43/src/share/native/java/lang/Thread.c  You'll have to grep around a little to find the implementations.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292629/where-to-find-source-code-for-java-lang-native-methods

Comment: Since all the implementations are OS-specific, you will most likely end up somewhere in `os_foo.cpp`, e.g. for Linux, `JVM_yield()` ends up in http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/hotspot/file/c9f8b7319d0a/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp#l3827, where it finally calls `sched_yield()`.